# rsync complex filter

Tags: filter, rsync

I was an Unison fan but I need more complicated filters to back up my laptop. 
After hours of trying I obtained for the most part what I want; this is my situation:

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -aHAXzhv --dry-run \
--progress \
--stats \
--delete \
--prune-empty-dirs \
--filter="merge filter" \
/ /media/mypassport/laptop/
```

and this is my filter:

```
+ etc
+ etc/apache2
+ etc/apache2/sites-available
+ etc/apache2/sites-available/*

+ home
+ home/ale
+ home/ale/*
+ home/ale/.filezilla/*
+ home/ale/.emacs.d/*
+ home/ale/.evolution/*
+ home/ale/.mozilla/*
+ home/ale/.ssh/*
+ home/ale/.subversion/*
+ home/ale/.unison/*

+ root
+ root/*
+ root/.c/*

+ usr/
+ usr/local/
+ usr/local/*

+ var/
+ var/www
+ var/www/*

+ *.git/***
+ *.svn/***
+ *.cvs/***

- etc/*
- etc/apache2/*

- home/ale/.** # this exclude hidden folder in ale's home

- var/*

- root/.**
- lib64
- initrd.img.old
- initrd.img
- vmlinuz
- vmlinuz.old

- *~
- .*~
- *.o
- *.tmp
- .*
- */
```

I would like to be able to exclude ALL hidden files in home folderS and include just few of them in this way:

```
+ home/*/.bashrc
- home/*/.*
```

but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards

Thank you